# The item obj\Debug\xxx.yyyForm.resources was specified more than once in the “Resources” parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

Visual Studio, C#.

After deleting many controls, and renaming the main class, I compiled and got this error: 
"The item obj\Debug\xxxx.yyyForm.resources was specified more than once in the Resources parameter." Where xxx is my project and yyy is my form.

Where is this "Resources parameter"?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

1. Through Windows Explorer, go to the project directory
2. Note that there are 2 files with the .resx extension: one named the same as the main class, one with a different name
3. Delete, move or rename the one with a different name
4. Close Visual Studio and reopen it
5. Go to the Solution Explorer tab
6. Note that the file you deleted is now listed (it wasn't before) with an "attention" icon
7. Select that file in the Solution Explorer tab and press the Delete key
8. Run; the problem goes away